# Remove Alias for Virtual Server

Tags: apache, configuration, webserver

need some help configuring local web server. I have an alias defined and a virtual web server.

```
Alias site /workspace/site/www/trunk/public
```

The thing is I do not want localhost.anothersite.com/site to point to /workspace/site/www/trunk/public. Is there a way to remove this alias from virtual server?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost.anothersite.com
 DocumentRoot /workspace/anothersite/public
 <Directory "/workspace/anothersite/public">
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Require all granted
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just comment the alias (with a **#**) and reload apache.

Comment: That't not what I am trying to do. I still want the alias to be used in my localhost/site, but it should be disabled in localhost.anothersite.com/site

Answer (score 0):

Override it in the VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost.anothersite.com
 DocumentRoot /workspace/anothersite/public
 Alias /site /workspace/anothersite/public/site
</VirtualHost>
```